# how to specify the database in the config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

I made a website. I use sqlite3.
database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'populate'
gem 'faker'
gem 'russian', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.8'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'factory_girl'
gem 'database_cleaner'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

on the local server it is running. I uploaded it to heroku. as a result of getting the following error message:

> 500 internal server error

heroku uses postgresql. that's the problem. please help set up configuration

Comment: Please do some basic research before posting questions, and let us know what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as it says: You need to add `pg` gem. Include the following line in your Gemfile

```
gem 'pg', group: :production
```

And you in your **config/database.yml** file, you can write the following code with appropriate modifications:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: password1

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: password1

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_prouduction
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: password1
```